# Show that the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x}{x+n}=0$ for $x\geq 0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, self-learning

This proof is my first proof for convengence of series of function. I have not seen any example that show how to proof in the book. I did it base on the proof of sequence of number
Please check my proof

For $\epsilon >0$ we must find $N$ that $N\leq n$

$$ \frac{x}{x+n}<\frac{x}{n}$$

$$\frac{x}{n}<\epsilon $$

$$\frac{x}{\epsilon }<n$$

Choose $N\geq \frac{x}{\epsilon }$

Then  $\frac{x}{x+n}<\frac{x}{n}\leq N< n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to find, given $\varepsilon>0$, some $N$ such that, for $n>N$,
$$
\left|\frac{x}{x+n}-0\right|<\varepsilon
$$
As $x\ge0$, the inequality can be written
$$
x<\epsilon x+\epsilon n
$$
so
$$
n\ge\frac{x(1-\varepsilon)}{\varepsilon}
$$
Take the least positive integer $N$ such that
$$
N>\frac{x(1-\varepsilon)}{\varepsilon}
$$
and you're done.

---

Your method of observing that
$$
\frac{x}{x+n}\le \frac{x}{n}
$$
is as good, but you should phrase it better.